# Calculating residuals of two curves with different datapoints in R

Tags: r, plot, interpolation

I have two different datasets (`c1` and `c2`), which are plotted together in one graph. both curves have different x- and y-values:

```
c1 = data.frame(
  x=c(0,1.1,2,  3,  4,  5),
  y=c(0,1.1,1.9,3.2,4.3,5.2)
)
c2 = data.frame(
  x=c(0,0.3,0.9,2.1,3.2,4.2,5),
  y=c(0,0.4,1.5,2.3,3.2,4.1,5.1)
)
plot(c1, type="o", col=2)
lines(c2, type="o", col=3)
```

Now I like to plot the residuals of the two curves (`res=c1-c2`) for all unique x values (`unique(c(c1$x, c2$x))`). This would be easy if I had the same x-values. But it seems, that I have to interpolate all missing x-values and add them to the measured dataset.

Is there an easy way for doing this in R?

Comment: When you say "residuals" do you mean the differences between the line segments on your charts? If so, for what x-values do you want the difference?

Comment: For all existing x-values in the two curves (`unique(c1$x, c2$x)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

On the values `c1$x`:

```
c1$y - approx(c2$x, c2$y, c1$x)$y
# [1]  0.0000000 -0.5333333 -0.3333333  0.1636364  0.3800000  0.1000000
```

on the values `c2$x`:

```
approx(c1$x, c1$y, c2$x)$y - c2$y
# [1]  0.00 -0.10 -0.60 -0.27  0.22  0.38  0.10
```

Or, putting it all together,

```
x <- sort(unique(c(c1$x, c2$x)))
approx(c1$x, c1$y, x)$y - approx(c2$x, c2$y, x)$y
# [1] 0.0000000 -0.1000000 -0.6000000 -0.5333333 -0.3333333 -0.2700000  0.1636364  0.2200000
# [9] 0.3800000  0.3800000  0.1000000
```